# How to work with multiple promise and resolve with Promise.all?

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to put multiple promises inside an array and when i am console the promiseArray getting an empty array.don't know how it prints an empty array. and userRecord is the auth and inside that email is there i am resolving then i am trying to solve the problem in this way

```
const fn = async campaign => {
  const promiseArray = [];
  if (campaign.stage === "active") {
    userRecord.map(async data => {
      if (data.email !== "" && data.email !== undefined) {
        const sendEmail = await SES.sendRawEmail(params).promise();
        promiseArray.push(sendEmail);
      }
    });
  }
  if (campaign.stage === "joined") {
    userRecord.map(async data => {
      if (data.email !== "" && data.email !== undefined) {
        const sendEmailJoined = await SES.sendRawEmail(params).promise();
        promiseArray.push(sendEmailJoined);
      }
    });
  }
console.log(promiseArray)
  //I am trying to resolve this in two ways
  await Promise.all(promiseArray);
  //here is the second method
  await Promise.all(
    promiseArray.map(async promise => {
      await promise;
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: It would be better if you can indent code correctly.

Comment: The content of both if blocks is the same, except for naming. Therefore, the code does not really make much sense. Could you please show what `userRecord` is?

Comment: _only the first promise_ do you mean the fastest promise?

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt i have updated the question and my problem

Comment: If your promise array is empty means that your logic prevents to fill it. debug it?

Comment: @luciferluci is `userRecord` an array or is it some fancy monadic promise implementation?

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt UserRecord is an array of objects

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

You are just a bit confused where to use async and await. Don't use it for your mapping functions and don't await the function when pushing it into your promise array.

```js
// helper function to simulate async
const SES = {
    sendRawEmail: async params => {
      return new Promise(res => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            console.log(params);
            res();
        }, Math.random() * 1000);
      });
    }
}

const fn = async campaign => {

    const promiseArray = [];
    // some sample data for simulation
    const userRecord = [{ email: "a@a.ch", params: 1 }, { email: "b@b.ch", params: 2 }, { email: "c@c.ch", params: 3 }, { email: "d@d.ch", params: 4 }];
    // I cleaned up your if a bit as you dublicate code here
    if (campaign.stage === "active" || campaign.stage === "joined") {
        // also don't use await here
        // replace map with forEach as it suits your problem better as @Benjamin Eckardt pointed out
        userRecord.forEach(data => {
            if (data.email) {
                // don't use await here
                // const sendEmailJoined = await SES.sendRawEmail(params).promise();
                // i made a little shortcut here
                promiseArray.push(SES.sendRawEmail(data));
            }
        });
    }

    await Promise.all(promiseArray)
    console.log("finish");
};

fn({ stage: "active" });
```

Comment: Just for clarifying the intention, I'd suggest replacing `userRecord.map(...)` with `userRecord.forEach(...)` since nothing is returned.